# Dell - no bootable device found - lubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows, dual-boot, lubuntu

I have an old computer (not that old), (dell version: inspiron 1338) with 8gb ram, core i3 and single 1tb hdd.
Since it ran a little slow i decided it was time for an "upgrade" to lubuntu which went smooth until it asked to restart.
Since then I'm stuck in: no bootable device found. I appears the bios isn't able to find the lubuntu boot files. However when i turn eufi and ... on i can still boot my windows 10.

When I boot and go the configuration, I am able to see the hdd. 
I didn't install the GRUB boot loader is this required?
Secure boot is disabled, eufi is turned on.

I'm sort of stuck, spend some time searching over the internet, no proposed answer worked (yet).

Expected outcome: being able to boot in lubuntu (ubuntu lightweight distro) and when changing the boot options boot back into windows so i don't lose my files there (or is there another way to dual-boot?).

ps. i'm fairly new to linux and stuff, please be kind <3

edit on first comment: it appears to be that the pc can't find lubuntu so i can't add it in the bios to boot first

Comment: You migh wanna check boot order inside bios, make sure ubuntu/grub loads first

Comment: @sn99 see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was the following: installing ubuntu and then lubuntu, managed to clear my issues with grub